# Pass polymorphic type as argument in SoapUI when using ServiceKnownType in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, soapui, datacontract, serviceknowntype

I have a WCF Service; this service has an operation that receives an argument of type `Request`. This is only the base type, and when calling the operation we actually send a value of type `Request_V1` (which inherts from `Request`), that has the complete implementation of the request I want to send.

When trying to test the service using soapUI, I'm able to create the complex type of type `Request_V1` (adding the proper namespace) but for some reason, the service is receiving the value as if it were of `Request` type.

Reading about `ServiceKnowType`, I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758062/understanding-serviceknowntype-in-wcf) that I need to specify somehow explicitly in the client this inheritance relationship, but I haven't found any info regarding how to do it on soapUI

Has anybody experienced and solved the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out? If yes, can you please explain the possible solution. I am having a similar issue

Comment: no luck so far, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

You also have to specify the type in the SOAP message.
For example

> ```
> <Request i:type="d:RequestV1">
> ```
>
> ...

where i is defined as XML-Instance namespace

Answer (score 1):

On service side, you need to typecast to specific derived type.

```
operation (Request request){
    if(!(request is Request_V1)){
        throw Excetion("Unknown type!");
    }

    var request_v1 = Request as Request_V1;

    // use request_v1
}
```

On SOAP UI side, specify type as below:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ns1:OperationName>
     <ns1:request i:type="ns2:Request_V1">
```

Make sure you have defined ns1 and ns2 before referring to them.

Comment: That is already set, the problem is (was) how to make the proper envelope in SoapUI

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the inheritance in the client, rather in the service. SOAPUI shouldn't have a problem with that. Check you have the correct declarations on your data contracts. This might help - [Deserialize Abstract Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634040/deserialize-abstract-class/634191#634191).

Comment: All the needed `KnownType` attributes have been already added to the DataContract, but for some reason is not working :(